# Why does return type of the methods are abstract?

Tags: android, methods

Link:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#NONE

In the above link everymethod has abstract added to it .Which class or classes implement the menu interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it mean?

It means that [those methods are abstract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). From the standpoint of JavaDocs, all methods on an interface are abstract.

> Which class or classes implement the menu interface?

Towards the top of the page, you will see: "Known Indirect Subclasses", with links to [`ContextMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html) and [`SubMenu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SubMenu.html). Those are two that happen to be visible in the Android SDK. There may be others, that are part of the Android framework but are not visible in the Android SDK. And you are welcome to create your own implementation of the `Menu` interface, if you wish.

Comment: sir I was confused.I rephrased my question.Can you answer my query?